Do I need a gate resistor for the LT1158 driver?
I am running an LTspice simulation for a half bridge using the LT1158 Driver and SQJ422EP MOSFET.
In the simulation once I put two 1 K gate resistors (for both MOSFETs) the output goes to zero.
I am trying to understand if this is a problem is with LTspice or if the LT1158 have a protection for gate capacitance charging already.
Do I even have to put gate resistors once I'm using a dedicated driver?
Vout trace and schematic with driver, gate resistors and half bridge:


"detecated" -> dedicated?

1 kΩ is far too high for a MOSFET gate resistor; it will turn on so slowly that, unless your PWM signal is incredibly slow, it will turn back off before it turns on.
More usual gate resistances are in the range of about 1~10 Ω. Try something in that range.
You only need a gate resistor if high switching speed is causing an issue (excessive ringing is a common one, as is EMI); the gate resistor acts to slow down switching. Note that a larger gate resistor also means higher switching losses due to the slower switching.

Another issue: The GateFB pins must be connected directly to the gates if resistors are used, as shown in figure 1, 6, 7 and 15 of the datasheet or the shoot through prevention does not work.

1k gate resistors seem a bit excessive, usually they are in the order of 10R. Depending on your signal frequency, you might not be able to charge the G-S capacitances.

MOSFET gates have no current flow, so you dont need 1Kohm of resistance, its way too high. The voltage drops to a value that cannot open the gate.
What you need is lower resistance, something under 100ohm (I can't recommend an exact value).

You might need a gate resistor for that capacitance

I forgot about that, thanks.
